# Merging DLL Files with ILMerge in PowerShell IIS - String is too long (multiple lines)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, iis, dll

I want to merge many Dll Files with ILMerge, but everytime the parameter string gets longer than the screen I get an error.

Start-Process ilmerge.exe "File1.dll File2.dll File3.dll /out:C:\MyFolder"  **--> works fine!**

Start-Process ilmerge.exe "File1.dll File2.dll File3.dll
File4.dll File5.dll ..... /out:C:\MyFolder"                                **--> doesn't work**

I want to give ilmerge.exe many files at once (all dll files from the folder) so I put
them into a variable including the outputfolder

Start-Process ilmerge.exe $MyDLLsAndFolder **--> works fine too, but just when the string is only in one line**

Any help would be great :)!

Answer (score 0):

Please use `-argumentList` to hand over your parameters, see if the error persists.

```
Start-Process ilmerge.exe -argumentlist @("File1.dll", "File2.dll" ...)
```

Regards Paul